# Make changes inopening program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How do I opened the program (for example : Word,Paint ) by run WindowsApplication and then Make changes in it (for example write text in the Word)?

Comment: Where to start.....
What have you tried? Have you any code? What is your actual goal here?
You will need to be a lot more specific if you want a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

You can open the `MS-Word file` using this class. edit it in file's editor selected by OS. and when you close, the `Process` object will be notified.

The link also has a sample programs below.

Comment: I kind of assumed the OP was looking to edit the file programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the *Microsoft.Office.Interop* namespace if you want programmatical access to ms office programs.